# Qt program fails to run with errors referencing libwinpthread-1

Tags: c++, qt, dependencies

I've made a C++/OpenGL application using the Qt framework, but I cannot to run `*.exe` file. I always get errors with `libwinpthread-1`.

I already read articles about that, but all dll's are in the `Qt` folder, so I don't understand what the problem is. Please take a look at my `*.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    sliceobj.cpp


unix|win32: LIBS += -lOPENGL32
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../5.0.2/mingw47_32/lib/ -lglut32

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-unknown-pragmas


INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../5.0.2/mingw47_32/include

win32 {
    message("* Using settings for windows")
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\opencv\\build\\include" \
                   "C:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv" \
                   "C:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2"

    LIBS += -L"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc11\\bin" \
        -lopencv_core247\
        -lopencv_highgui247\
        -lopencv_imgproc247\
        -lopencv_video247\

    LIBS += -L"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc11\\staticlib" \
        -lopencv_core247\
        -lopencv_highgui247\
        -lopencv_imgproc247\
        -lopencv_video247\
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It looks like you are mixing MinGW and Visual Studio in the same application. That will not work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what exactly your code links against + Which libraries are loaded in runtime. Open your executable with DW and you will see DLL's that are linked against. They need to be present in PATH or beside your executable. Press F7 to start profiling to see which libraries are loaded in runtime. Here as snapshot:

[image]

Comment: This should not have been an answer, but a comment. It helps with debugging steps, but it does not actually answer the concern at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i know that's not good, but i'm just added this files into debug directory .
[image]